# Logic: LPL and Fitch Sentence Structure

Tags: logic

I am using the program Fitch from LPL (*Openproof Courseware: Language, Proof, and Logic*) and for some reason I am getting an error that the statement below "is not a sentence".

The statement is:

> ∀x∀y∀z(((Cube(x)∧Dodec(y))→Larger(x,y)) ∧
>   ((Dodec(y)∧Tet(z))→Larger(y,z))) → ((Cube(x)∧Dodec(y)∧Tet(z)) →
>   Larger(x,z))

From my understanding, there are essentially two reasons for why a quantified statement would not be deemed a sentence:

(1) There are unbounded variables (but in this case, there are not, all variables, x,y, and z, are binded to a universal quantifier).

(2) The parenthesis are off (in this case, I think made sure every statement that needed parenthesis included parenthesis).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *are* missing parentheses: you need one more at the beginning and one more at the end, like so:

> ∀x∀y∀z((((Cube(x)∧Dodec(y))→Larger(x,y)) ∧
>   ((Dodec(y)∧Tet(z))→Larger(y,z))) → ((Cube(x)∧Dodec(y)∧Tet(z)) →
>   Larger(x,z)))